# Indexes Definition Improvements - (Oracle DB)

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have the following table definition and want to improve indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE MATE (
    GUID NUMBER(38,0),
    SITE_KEY NUMBER(38,0),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(200),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(200),   
    BOOKING_NUM VARCHAR2(200),
    RELEASE_DATE DATE,
    STATUS VARCHAR2(200), -- Contains 'ACTIVE', 'RELEASED', 'DELETED', 'EXCLUDED', 'INACTIVE' and NULL
    CONSTRAINT SYS_C008630 CHECK ("GUID" IS NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT SYS_C008631 CHECK ("SITE_KEY" IS NOT NULL),
    CONSTRAINT SYS_C008632 PRIMARY KEY (GUID, SITE_KEY),
    CONSTRAINT FK8100EDAADECFC243 FOREIGN KEY (SITE_KEY) REFERENCES SITES<KEY>()
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SYS_C008632 ON MATE (GUID, SITE_KEY);  -- This is the PK (1)
CREATE INDEX IDX_STATUS ON MATE (STATUS);  -- (2)
CREATE INDEX IDX_SITE_KEY ON MATE (SITE_KEY); -- (3)
CREATE INDEX IDX_BOOKING_NUMBER ON MATE (BOOKING_NUM); -- (4)
CREATE INDEX IDX_FNAME ON MATE (FIRST_NAME); -- (5)
CREATE INDEX IDX_LNAME ON MATE (LAST_NAME); -- (6)
CREATE INDEX BRIAN2_IX ON MATE (SITE_KEY,BOOKING_NUM); -- (7)
CREATE INDEX IDX_SITE_STATUS ON MATE (SITE_KEY,STATUS); -- (8)
CREATE INDEX IDX_PIN_SITEKEY ON MATE (BOOKING_NUM,SITE_KEY); -- (9)
CREATE INDEX IDX_SITE_NAME_STATUS ON MATE (SITE_KEY,LAST_NAME,STATUS); -- (10)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_GUID_SITE_BOOKING ON MATE (GUID, SITE_KEY, BOOKING_NUM); -- (11)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IXU_SITE_BOOKING_GUID ON MATE (SITE_KEY, BOOKING_NUM, RELEASE_DATE, GUID); -- (12)
```

Is logical to:

1. Drop Index (7) because is already defined in (9)?
2. Drop Index (3) because is the left most in (8) and (10)?
3. Drop index (4) because is the left most in (9)?
4. Drop index (12) because SITE_KEY, BOOKING_NUM, GUID is already as UNIQUE Index in (11)?
5. Any other improvement?

Comment: The answer to all questions (or almost all, anyway) is "it depends". It depends on why you defined the indexes in the first place. Note that the order of columns in an index matters, sometimes significantly; so questions 1. and 4. don't make a lot of sense. Other questions are more subtle; if you have an index on columns C1 and C2 for some good reason, you may still also want one on C1 alone, if you just select C1 by itself often (and if C2 is significantly bigger than C1).

Comment: All queries can run without indexes. The question is... which queries do you want to optimize?

Comment: Indexes 3,4 and 7 have covering indexes so I'd suggest to drop them. And no - for you question 4.

Comment: And switch your primary key to use index IDX_GUID_SITE_BOOKING and then drop your old index SYS_C008632 .

Comment: How many rows in this table?  If under 100, you probably only need the indexes for the primary, unique and foreign keys. If a billion you might need all of them.  Probably the answer lies in between.  I've never seen so many indexes on a table with 7 columns, and suspect this is a case of over-zealous indexing for every eventuality - but of course I don't know the requirements!

Answer (score 2):

You can't optimize indexes *only* by looking at their definition. You need to know how the indexes are used before you remove them.

### Your Indexes Are Not Necessarily Redundant

For items #1 and #3, there are rare cases where you want to have two indexes that only differ based on the column order. For example, with the below two queries, it helps to have an index with both columns so you can avoid reading from the table. And the two different leading columns work better for each query. Having only one index is *usually* good enough, but maybe these are critical queries that need to be thoroughly optimized.

```
SELECT A, B FROM TABLE1 WHERE A = 1;
SELECT A, B FROM TABLE1 WHERE B = 2;
```

For items #2 and #4, the single-column indexes may be optimized for filtering, whereas the multi-column indexes may be optimized for index fast full scans (where the index acts like a skinny version of the table). For example, with the below queries, the first one runs best with an index on only column A, because that index is smaller and will be faster to read and more likely to fit in your cache. But the second query works best if there is an index on (A,B,C). Having the single, larger index is *usually* good enough, but not always.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE A = 1;
SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE1;
```

### Which Indexes Are Necessary?

To find out which indexes are necessary, you should use [index usage tracking](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/index-usage-tracking-12cr2). Fully optimizing indexes is a long, difficult process. But if you've gathered a list of suspicious indexes, and they are not used by *any* SQL statements, then they're probably safe to drop.

```
--Check that index statsitics are collected.
select * from gv$index_usage_info;

--Check which indexes are used.
select * from dba_index_usage order by last_used desc;

--Find recent SQL statements that used the index.
select * from gv$sql_plan where object_owner = 'JHELLER' and object_name = 'TEST1_IDX';

--Find historical SQL statements that used the index.
select * from dba_hist_sql_plan where object_owner = 'JHELLER' and object_name = 'TEST1_IDX';
```